# ¿Cuál es la mejor forma para actualizar una entidad en Symfony2?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony2

He creado nuevos campos en mi base de datos, el problema viene que al acceder ahora me pone que los `getters` y `setter` no están definidos, pero si le doy a generar `getters` y `setters` no me sale ninguna forma de actualizar ya que dice que está todo en orden, no consigo encontrar donde está el fallo.

¿Alguna idea de como actualizar y/o incluir los `getters` y `setters`?

Comment: A mí me pasó y lo tuve que hacer a mano.

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que hayas definido y mapeado los nuevos campos en la entidad correspondiente, puedes actualizar los métodos usando el comando de consola de symfony

Para Symfony 2

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities {EntitiyNamespaceShortcut}
```

Para Symfony 3

```
php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities {EntitiyNamespaceShortcut}
```

Por ejemplo, para una supuesta entidad llamada AppBundle\Entity\Common\Category usaríamos, en SF3

```
php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle:Common/Category
```

Si la entidad no está directamente bajo el namespace AppBundle\Entity, usa como separador `/` en lugar de `\` .

En lo sucesivo, en lugar de modificar la base de datos, deberías modificar la entidad en cuestión, ejecutar el comando `doctrine:generate:entities`, y seguidamente usar `doctrine:schema:update --force` para que Doctrine se encargue de actualizar la base de datos. No uses esto en producción, en su lugar utiliza --dump-sql y ejecútalas a mano o busca información sobre el plugin DoctrineMigration.